# How can I call a component with data property different? (vue.js 2)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-resource

My view is like this :

```
<!-- By Players -->
<div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="nav-cat-text">By Players</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
        <div class="wrap-tabs">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-cat">
                @foreach($by_players as $category)
                    @php 
                    if($loop->first)
                        $category_id = $category->id
                    @endphp
                    <li role="presentation" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tab" @click="$refs.player.getPlayer({{ $category->id }})">{{ ucfirst($category->name) }}</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">
        <top-player-view category_id="{{ $category_id }}" ref="player"></top-player-view>
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<!-- By Types -->
<div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="nav-cat-text">By Types</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
        <div class="wrap-tabs">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-cat">
                @foreach($by_types as $category)
                    @php 
                    if($loop->first)
                        $category_id = $category->id
                    @endphp
                    <li role="presentation" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tab" @click="$refs.player.getPlayer({{ $category->id }})">{{ ucfirst($category->name) }}</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" >
        <top-player-view category_id="{{ $category_id }}" ref="player"></top-player-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

My top player view component is like this :

```
<template>    
    ...
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:['category_id'],
        mounted() {
            const payload = {category_id: this.category_id}
            this.$store.dispatch('getTopPlayers', payload)
        },
        methods: {
            getPlayer: function(category_id) {
                const payload = {category_id: category_id}
                this.$store.dispatch('getTopPlayers', payload)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

After the code executed, data on by players = data on by types. Whereas the property data transmitted is different. Besides, when I click on any tab, the data shown on by players and by types are the same

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying that the data isn't there when it is first rendered.  If that is the case, mounted is only called after the $el has already been populated, so you should move the dispatch to a lifecyle event that is before the initial rendering.  Your best option is `beforeCreate`

Check out the fully lifecycle here.  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html